# Change height of subplots in cufflinks QuantFig() candlestick chart when using iplot(asFigure=True)

Tags: plotly, quantitative-finance, candlestick-chart, cufflinks, iplots

my problem is that all sublots of my technical analysis study in cufflinks QuantFig() are the same height when using iplot(asFigure=True). I want to increase the height of the top candlestick chart and decrease the height of the underlying indicators RSI, MACD and Volume and the entire indicator range. I would like to keep the edit functions in the upper right corner of the chart. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
import cufflinks as cf

qf = cf.QuantFig(df_ticker, kind='candlestick', legend='right', name=ticker)

# Technical Analysis Studies for example:
qf.add_rsi(periods=20, color='java')
qf.add_macd(fast_period=12, slow_period=26, signal_period=9)
qf.add_volume()

# then plot by:
self.fig = self.qf.iplot(asFigure=True, dimensions=(1000, 600), up_color='green', down_color='red')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGWNO.png)

Comment: have you found the solution? I am looking for exact solution as well. Thanks for sharing.